# MySQL Exception "PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42000]"

Tags: php, mysql, iis

I am newbie to PHP and MySQL. I was trying install `http://sourceforge.net/projects/candidats/` php software. While installing or loading data to database in the installation process I got below error. Can some help me to right direction?

```
    PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 
    1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
    MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘IGNORE TABLE email_history ADD COLUMN for_module varchar(255) 
    default NULL’ at line 1 [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 42000 [file:protected] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Cats\lib\ClsNaanalPDO.php 
    [line:protected] => 124 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Cats\lib\ClsNaanalPDO.php [line] => 124 [function] => execute [class] => 
PDOStatement [type] => -> [args] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( 
[file] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Cats\lib\ClsNaanalPDO.php [line] => 
555 [function] => query [class] => ClsNaanalPDO [type] => 
-> [args] => Array ( [0] => ALTER IGNORE TABLE email_history ADD COLUMN for_module 
varchar(255) default NULL ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] =>
 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\\Cats\lib\DatabaseConnectionPDO.php 
[line] => 149 [function] => setQuery [class] => ClsNaanalPDO 
[type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0] => ALTER IGNORE TABLE 
email_history ADD COLUMN for_module varchar(255) default NULL ) ) 
[3] => Array ( [file] => C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Cats\modules\install\ajax\ui.php [line] => 1172
 [function] => query [class] => DatabaseConnection [type] => -> 
[args] => Array ( [0] => ALTER IGNORE TABLE email_history 
ADD COLUMN for_module varchar(255) default NULL ) ) [4] => Array ( [file] =>
```

Comment: What's your MySQL version? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html "_As of MySQL 5.7.4, the IGNORE clause for ALTER TABLE is removed and its use produces an error._"

Comment: Server version: 5.7.10-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Looks like that's the reason then. ALTER IGNORE is no longer supported, so you'll probably have dig those out of the code and change them to simply `ALTER`, and hope for no index violations.